# Creating YouTube playlist in real time

Tags: youtube

Is there any possibility to create a YouTube playlist that will work in a real time.

All viewers will watch the same content at the same time as the traditional television.

https://viloud.tv offers this feature, but I wonder is there some script or way of embedding to achive the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to start a live stream.